# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'element_to_be_clickable'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, attributeerror

> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute
>   'element_to_be_clickable'

```
from telnetlib import EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

select = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="form-validation-field-0"]'))))
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'element_to_be_clickable'
```

Answer (score 10):

The import `from telnetlib import EC`. You need to import `expected_conditions` and use it as `EC`

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```